# bootstrap-confiirmation doesn't handle method :delete in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to use bootstrap-confirmation for an index view with datatables and a column for deleting the row item. I have it working without the confirmation, or with the default confirmation, but not with bootstrap-confirmation, it sends me to the show method, rather than the delete method of the controller. Its like it doesnt see the method: :delete

Here is the way I'm calling it in the index view. The popup confirmation displays, but when I click ok, it sends me to the show page.

```
<td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>'.html_safe, role_path(id: role.id), method: :delete, :'data-toggle' => 'confirmation', :'data-copy-Attributes' => 'href data-method'%></td>
```

This following works (without confirmation), so I know my routes, controller action, etc work.

```
<td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>'.html_safe, role_path(id: role.id), method: :delete, %></td>
```

Any ideas?

Heres my view:

```
<h1> Roles</h1>
</br>

<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="roles-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Roles</th>
      <th>User Count</th>
      <th>Delete Role</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @roles.each do |role| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= role.name %>
      <td><%= role.users.count %></td>
      <% if (role.users.count == 0) %>
        <!--td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>'.html_safe, role_path(id: role.id), method: :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}%></td-->
        <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>'.html_safe, role_path(id: role.id), method: :delete, :'data-toggle' => 'confirmation', :'data-copy-Attributes' => 'href data-method'%></td>

      <% else %><
        <td></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= link_to "Add Role", new_role_path, class: "btn btn-success"%>
```

Comment: Could you try with `<td>
  <%= link_to role, method: :delete, data: { toggle: 'confirmation', copy: { Attributes: 'href data-method' } } do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
  <% end %>
</td>`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same issue. Goes to the show page. Looks like the delete method isnt getting passed with the syntax you provided, because when I inspect the popup confirmation button, it shows:

<a href="/roles/20" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-apply="confirmation"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Yes</a>

Comment: Could you add your view?

Comment: I pasted my view in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: With my original link_to that I posted, it does look right in the generated html (meaning it has the data-method), but still goes to the show page
    <a href="/roles/25" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-apply="confirmation" data-method="delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Yes</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make the library work because it doesn't provide a way to edit the popup html it generates, so, it also took for me the link to the `show` method and no way to delete it.

So what I did was to create a route to delete the resource that expects to receive the `id` from the resource and a value in the params for `delete`:

```
get 'role/:id/:delete', to: 'role#show', as: 'show_role'
```

Then in your controller you can check if you're receving a `delete` param, in order to separate between `show` and `destroy`, if you receive it, then  you destroy it and redirects to the `roles_url`:

```
def show
  @role = Role.find(params[:id])
  if params[:delete]
    @role.destroy
    redirect_to roles_url
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can use a `link_to` helper, passing the route created previously passing the resource and a value for the `delete` param, adding the data attributes Bootstrap Confirmation needs to make it work:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', show_role_path(role, delete: true), data: { toggle: 'confirmation', title: 'Delete it?' } %>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for taking a look at this. While your solution is creative, I really don't want to use a confirmation that requires routing tweaks, as every controller is going to need this, so I guess I will have to use a different confirmation type. Maybe the sweetalert2, as it uses the regular rails method with data-confirm